# Directing functions with Jquery directly to single instances of a class

Tags: jquery, class, animation

I have a series of `<div>`'s with the same class that are auto generated by a system. They have no ID values to it. I am trying to change the properties of the single instances of the class.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class = 'test'>
  <ul>
     <li>something</li>
     <li>something</li>
     <li>something</li>
     <li>something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class = 'test'>
  <ul>
     <li>something</li>
     <li>something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that all of the `<div>`s are collapsed to just show the first `<li>something</li>` if you click the `<div>` then it expands to its full size.

The problem I have is that the amount of `<li>`'s can change as the content can be uploaded.

I'm trying to obtain each of the div's height before using jquery to set the css height properies to only show the first `<li>` of each div. Then on a click event of the div's expand to their full size.

Here's my Jquery:

```
var height = ('.test').height());


$('.test').css('height','25');

$('.test').click(function(){
    $(this).animate('height', height);
});
```

I can't get the function to work directly to the single instance of the class object.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThePagan/pKzTb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.test').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').hide().eq(0).show();
});
$('.test').click(function() {
    $(this).find('li').show();
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2aJhu/)

Comment: Nice one, this works enough for me to take it further. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `not(:first-child)` selector to get the `li` elements which are not the first child.

```
$('li:not(:first-child)').hide();

$('.test').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        list = $this.find('li:not(:first-child)');
    $this.data('collapsed', !$this.data('collapsed'));
    $this.data('collapsed') ? list.fadeIn() : list.fadeOut();
});
```

**[SEE THE WORKING DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/pKzTb/2/)**

Comment: yeah! i like this strategy more than mine. still i think there has to be event delegation as OP mentioned _I have a series of <div>'s with the same class that are auto generated by a system._....not sure but i think there should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
var h = $('.test').find('li:eq(0)').height();

$('.test').css({'height': h, 'overflow' : 'hidden'});

$(document).on('click', '.test', function(){ // delegate the event
    if($(this).css('overflow') === 'hidden'){
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    }else{
        $(this).css({'height': h, 'overflow' : 'hidden'});
    }
});
```

---

You need to have a event delegation because as you mentioned that it is system generated, I have delegated to the `$(document)` but you can delegate to the element which was available when page was first loaded like parent of `.test`.